# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime on DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I know there is a lot of asked question here about `DateTime` but I saw them all already and seems not to find the right solution for my case.

Here is my code:

```
return DateTime.ParseExact(partialDate + dtfi.DateSeparator + _baseDate.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-us");
```

This is throwing me an Exception.

Here is the value of the variables:

```
string partialDate = "1/22";
string dtfi.DateSeparator = "/";
int _baseDate = 2004;
```

Comment: The date format for the `en-US` culture is `MM/dd/yyyy`, yet you specified `dd/MM/yyyy` as the format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unfortunately*, both answers are wrong.

So, we all agree your result string will be `"1/22/2004"`. Before looking which formats exactly matches your characters, let's look at your string is a standard date and time format for `en-US` culture or not.

```
DateTime.Parse("1/22/2004",
               CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) // 22 January 2004 00:00:00
```

#### BANG!

We have a `DateTime` perfectly. But what if our string wouldn't be a standard date and time format for `en-US` culture? Then we can specify our format with [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx). Let's look at which formats we can use to parsing our string.

- `1` matches with [`"M"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#M_Specifier) which is from `1` to `12` and single-digit month is formatted *without* a leading zero.
- `/` is a [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) and we can use it the same in our format because `en-US` culture has `/` as a `DateSeparator` already. Remember, [`"/"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of *replace me with current culture or supplied culture date separator*
- `22` matches with [`"dd"` custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ddSpecifier) which is from `01` to `31` and single-digit days is formatted *with* a leading zero. *Remember*, you can also use d format specifier in such a case but using *wider* formats is recommended.
- `2004` matches with [`"yyyy"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#yyyySpecifier) which represents the year with a four digits.

So, the *right* format will be `M/dd/yyyy` in result.

```
string s = "1/22/2004";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt); // 22 January 2004 00:00:00
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use format `"m/dd/yyyy"` because datestring becomes `1/22/2004`

```
return DateTime.ParseExact(partialDate + dtfi.DateSeparator + _baseDate.ToString(), "m/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-us"));
```

Comment: @Gerald: When you are using ParseExact, your string should come in exactly same format else it will throw exception. You can use TryParseExact instead.

Comment: Even DateTime.Parse would work if you specify the correct culture (en-US). Why then use ParseExact?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - i did try using the DateTime.Parse with culture but it didn't work.

Comment: What did you try? The following statements work without problem: `DateTime.Parse("12/22/2004",new CultureInfo("en-US"));` and `DateTime.Parse("1/22/2004",new CultureInfo("en-US"));` Are you sure you aren't encountering a typo or data error?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to wrong format, so obviously it will throw exception.  Below is what you are doing

```
string partialDate = "1/22";
string dtfi.DateSeparator = "/";
int _baseDate = 2004;

string ex = partialDate + dtfi.DateSeparator + _baseDate.ToString();
```

which gives you `1/22/2014 i.e., MM/dd/yyyy`

and in code you are referring to

```
return DateTime.ParseExact(partialDate + dtfi.DateSeparator + _baseDate.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-us");
```

Try using correct Format, to get the right result.